# Tascam DR 05, recording with both external and internal mics

Tags: microphone, tascam, track, external

I have recently bought a [Tascam - DR-05](http://tascam.com/product/dr-05/specifications/), and two [Lavaliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavalier_microphone).

I have read the manual of the Tascam - DR-05, and I have also browsed on the internet, but I can not figure out if I can record both the external mics (for instance with one lavalier) and with the internal (built-in) microphone at the same time, i.e., can I get whether separate or a single track with both sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to manual, when you plug in your external microphones, the internal will be disabled. I have the same feature in my Sony Pcm-m10 and it is a bit frustrating, but I guess it's because of the size of the recorder - to record 4 channels you will need more Preamps, that are difficult to place inside small device.

Comment: So sad, thank you for your response. I thought it would give me more autonomy when recording on locations, but I think that I can still connect one lavalier to the camera, and record ambient with the tascam.

Comment: It's the same with the DR-100 too; it's a 2-Channel recorder, so either internal or external mic, not both. I think you might be able to use the Zoom H4N in this way though (4-Channels,  2 External & 2 Internal), but haven't used a H4N myself.